# How to solve overdetermined system $Ax=b$ using least squares, given a matrix $M$, where $M^T A$ is upper triangular and $M^TM$ is a diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m>n$. How can I solve the full rank least squares problem if I am given a matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that $M^TA = S$ and $M^TM = D$, where $S$ is upper triangular and $D$ is diagonal?

Comment: If $M$ is nonsingular, then $M$ is just a diagonal scaling of the Q-factor of a QR factorization $A=QR$  with $Q=MD^{-1/2}$ and $R=D^{1/2}S$. If you know how to use it to solve your LS problem, you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is not clear to me what facts led us to $Q=MD^{-1/2}$ and $R = D^{1/2}S$. Is there a special structure that is obvious from the problem statement?

Comment: If $M$ is nonsingular, then, since $M^TM=D$, with $Q:=MD^{-1/2}$, we have $Q^TQ=D^{-1/2}M^TMD^{-1/2}=D^{-1/2}DD^{-1/2}=I$ so the matrix $Q$ is orthogonal. From, $M^TA=S$, we have $D^{-1/2}M^TA=Q^TA=D^{-1/2}S=:R$, where $R$ is upper triangular (sorry my first $R$ was wrong). So $A=QR$ is a QR factorization of $A$.

Comment: Ah I see, I couldn't see that I can rescale matrix $M$ to make it some $Q$ factor for $QR$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given $M^TM = D$, we can do

$$M^TM = D^{1/2}D^{1/2} \rightarrow D^{-1/2} M^TMD^{-1/2} = I = Q^TQ$$
$$Q = MD^{-1/2}$$

(We view this as scaling $M$ with $D^{1/2}$ to get some orthogonal $Q$)

Now using our $Q$, we upper-triangularize A (and using $M^TA = S$)

$$Q^TA = D^{-1/2}M^TA = D^{-1/2}S = R$$

Now we can solve the least squares problem with $Q=MD^{-1/2}$ and $R = D^{-1/2}S$